# Is the Windows SDK on Windows 10 not compatible with Windows XP and lower?

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk, compatibility

I tried running a basic c++ app that displayed a window. The API functions it used were compatible with Windows XP, but the app itself would not run on my Windows XP VM.

It was compiled on Windows 10 and some googling showed me an answer from here that said the Windows 10 SDK is not compatible with Windows XP or lower.

Why is that? Are the prototypes and function names not all the same?

If not, which SDK should I use to maybe get compatibility across the board?

Comment: of course sdk header/lib files compatible with Windows XP. your app not run faster of all because you set OperatingSystemVersion from `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` higer that *5.1* or use some api not exist on xp

Comment: guess you need set [`/SUBSYSTEM:*,5.1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019) if you not already done this

Comment: I am not sure exactly what that was, so I used MAKEWORD(5,1) and set that value on the subsystem settings and now I get the same error I used to get on Windows XP running on my main Windows 10 computer. I just want it to be compatible with all versions, bro.

Comment: @AbcDef This can't be answered if you don't post the code and the compiler/linker command lines.

Comment: You also need to tell us how your program fails on XP.

Comment: I get an error saying something like "this is not a valid win32 application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, some time ago default platform toolset dropped Windows XP support. You can switch to another platform toolset from menu `Project->project name Properties...` then `Configuration properties->General->Platform toolset`. There you can change toolset used for current project

[image: platform toolset selection]

But XP toolset could be not istalled.

[Configuring Programs for Windows XP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019)

> **Install the Windows XP platform toolset**
>
> To get the v141_xp platform toolset and components to target Windows
> XP and Windows Server 2003, run the Visual Studio Installer. When you
> initially install Visual Studio, or when you modify an existing
> installation, make sure the Desktop development with C++ workload is
> selected. In the Individual components tab, under Compilers, build
> tools, and runtimes, choose C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141)
> tools [Deprecated], and then choose Install or Modify.